# Avoiding duplicate asynchronous service initialisations in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have an Angular.js service which delivers its results asynchronously, after looking around for a while the main pattern for doing this seems to be using $q promises like this

```
angular.module('fooApp').factory('foo', function ($q) {

    var result;

    function build() {
        var d = $q.defer();
        longAsyncInit(function(data) {
            result = data;
            d.resolve(result);
        });
        return d.promise; 
    };

    return {
        get: function () {
            if (result) {
                return $q.when(result);
            } else {
                return build();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that I have a number of services which have this service as a dependency and get is called multiple times before the first longAsyncInit ends (which means that longAsyncInit gets called multiple times, each time creating a new promise). In my case this is unacceptable, I really need longAsyncInit to be called once, no more. I'm currently addressing this issue like this

```
angular.module('fooApp').factory('foo', function ($q) {

    var result
    var d;

    function build() {
        d = $q.defer();
        longAsyncInit(function(data) {
            result = data;
            d.resolve(result);
        });
        return d.promise; 
    };

    return {
        get: function () {
            if (result) {
                return $q.when(result);
            } else if (d) {
                return d.promise;
            } else {
                return build();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This means if longAsyncInit is already ongoing when a get() call is made, it returns the current promise, instead of creating a new one and calling longAsyncInit again. This seems to work but feels inelegant and fragile, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I believe this code is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **debounce** method to solve problem.

From **Underscore** library documentation what `_.debounce()` do

> Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function
>   which will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have
>   elapsed since the last time it was invoked. Useful for implementing
>   behavior that should only happen after the input has stopped arriving.
>   For example: rendering a preview of a Markdown comment, recalculating
>   a layout after the window has stopped being resized, and so on.

- Some more explanations
  [Can someone explain the "debounce" function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)
- Some content to read:
  http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function