How to ensure web worker process only last message?
I have a scenario where it might happen that user produces events rapidly (hovers, e.g.). Each hover sends a message to web worker to do some calculation.
Each new message should cancel the previous one and I need to be sure only last one will be processed and its result returned back to UI thread.
How can I make sure that web worker processes only last message it receives?
I would like to avoid any debounce time as its important that delay is minimal.

Is it easy to cancel the processing that the web worker is doing?

@JaromandaX it is. Its basically a for loop which I can cancel in any iteration.

so, keep a count of how many messages have been sent. In the loop, if it's more than 1, reduce the number by 1 and exit the loop without sending a response, if the loop finishes, and the value is still 1, set it to 0 and respond to the main thread - that's a general overview, there are details you have to address with your code of course

@JaromandaX that sounds like a viable approach. I see just one caveat there. if the new message arrives in the middle of workers processing the loop, the message count would not be increased until the processing of loop is done. So i guess there should be some kind of event loop handling like timeout((),0) within a for loop to allow worker to increase the message count. thoughts?

Short of using SharedArrayBuffers to transmit the data instead of messaging, you'll need to debounce at least the event handler (and add a task delay inside the loop if you want to cancel it while it's running).

without code, I can't say

@Kaiido yep, thats what I thought. I cannot use SharedArtayBuffer for data exchange. Could you please put in answer an example of that you mean by debouncing event handler? (task delay inside loop is clear).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359805/javascript-web-worker-how-to-ignore-all-messages-except-the-last-one contains an example use underscore, but basically you just have to store the event somewhere in the actual event handler, wait like a single task (e.g. setTimeout(cb, 0)) before processing the event.

I created the NPM package @wjfe/async-workers that provides a class named CancellationSource.  This class uses SharedArrayBuffer to transmit the desire of cancelling a task to a web worker without the need of function generators or asynchronous programming.  You can simply use CancellationSource.throwIfSignaled() inside the FOR loop to cancel.
This class can be used on its own but I recommend you to use the AsyncWorker class because it simplifies the trouble of passing the buffer around and also provides a nice asynchronous syntax to the whole web worker usage.
An example:
// myWorker.ts
import { CancellationSource, workerListener, type PostFn, type Token } from "@wjfe/async-workers";

export const myWorker = {
  calculate(payload: Payload, _: PostFn, cancelToken: Token): MyData {
    for (let i = 0; i < someCap; ++i) {
      CancellationSource.throwIfSignaled(cancelToken);
      // Calculate
    }
    return result;
};

export type MyWorker = typeof myWorker;

self.onMessage = workerListener(myWorker);

Then in the UI thread:
// user-file.ts
import { myWorker } from "myWorker.js";

const worker = getWorkerSomehowDependingOnYourToolingSuchAsVite();

const controller = new AsyncWorker(worker, myWorker);

Now you can use controller to initiate the work:
// somewhere.ts
let workItem: WorkItem | undefined;

myElement.addEventListener('hover', () => {
  workItem?.cancel();
  workItem = controller.enqueue.calculate(undefined, { cancellable: true });
});

Or something like that.  Follow the repository's README for better accuracy.
What you see above, is an event listener that will first cancel the previous work item, and then generates a new work item every time the event fires.
IMPORTANT:  For this to work, you must satisfy the conditions for cross-origin isolation.
