# draggable drag event throttling

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am trying to make an animation on html5 canvas which is supposed to follow a draggable div when it is moved around, something like that:

```
draggable_div.draggable({
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        canvasDrawSomethingNearDraggable(ui);
    }
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        canvasDrawSomethingNearDraggable(ui);
    }
});

function canvasDrawRectangleUnderDraggable {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // draw overlapping circles in fixed order
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x[i], y[i], 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = c[i];
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

but the animation lags behind when I move the draggable element (the faster I move it the bigger the gap and it closes only when draggable stop event triggers):

[image]

Is there a way to solve or lessen this problem? Should I calculate time between drag events and make fewer calls to drawing function this way or is there a better solution?

Comment: it would be easier seeing your canvasDrawSomethingNearDraggable(ui) function, but you probably would get a better result drawing on drag start in a children of your draggable div so your canvas would move along.

Comment: added something very similar for illustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to debounce your function so the event handler doesn't get called too often (which slows everything down). See [Can someone explain the "debounce" function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript) for example.

An implementation of debounce is available within the Underscore library (http://underscorejs.org/#debounce). You can just copy that function to use in your code.

Comment: You mean throttle, not debounce.
If you debounce it, then a stream of events arriving every x milliseconds will not result in the handler being called until the stream stops.