# jQuery toggle fade display of element based on menu selection on mouseover

Tags: jquery, toggle, fadein, fadeout, onmouseover

Hi I have created a menu that you can make selection on either "mouseover" or "click" events.

see:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified keyword-navigation">
   <li class="active"><a href="#" data-displaypanel="#subjectcollection_A_C">A-  C</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#" data-displaypanel="#subjectcollection_D_H">D-H</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-displaypanel="#subjectcollection_I_N">I-N</a></li>
   ...
```

The result of making a selection is that I want it to fade out the previous/existing selected element and fade in the selected element that has an id that matches that specified by the data-displaypanel attribute.

This works fine...

```
<ul class="topic-blocks list-unstyled">
 <li class="keyword-panel" id="subjectcollection_A_C" style="display: list-
 ....
</li>
<li class="keyword-panel" id="subjectcollection_D_H" style="display: list-
 ....
</li>
```

However when you mouseover quickly between the different menu items it appears to be cancelling the fadeOut function before it has a chance to complete therefore leaving more than one element visible....

Is there any way to remedy this? I have tried various different methods with no luck.

```
$(".keyword-navigation li > a").on('click mouseenter', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ithis = $(this);
    if (!ithis.parent('li').hasClass('active')){
        var prevActivePanel = ithis.closest('.keyword-navigation')
                        .find('.active')
                        .removeClass('active')
                        .children('a')
                        .data('displaypanel'),
         currentActivePanel= ithis.parent('li')
                                .addClass('active')
                               .end()
                                 .data('displaypanel');


        $(prevActivePanel).fadeOut( "fast", function() {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
            $(currentActivePanel)
                .fadeIn( "fast", function() {
                    history.pushState(null, null, currentActivePanel);
                }).removeClass('hidden');

        });

    }

});
```

See my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/angusgrant/ov2zezmv/

Many thanks Angus

Answer (score 0):

The mouseenter event is triggered very quickly. In this cases you may use a [debounce(fn, wait)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/lang_functional) function. You may also take a look to [can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

If you want to stop the unwanted effect of mouseenter event (without debouncing) on your animation you need to change the following line:

```
$(prevActivePanel).fadeOut("fast", function() {
```

to:

```
$(prevActivePanel).stop().fadeOut("fast", function() {
```

The role of [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) is: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-keyword-navigation li > a:not(.disabled)").on('click mouseenter', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ithis = $(this),
        keywordNav = ithis.closest('.js-keyword-navigation');


    if (!ithis.parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
      keywordNav.find('a').addClass('disabled');
      var prevActivePanel = keywordNav
      .find('.active')
      .removeClass('active')
      .children('a')
      .data('displaypanel'),
          currentActivePanel = ithis.parent('li')
      .addClass('active')
      .end()
      .data('displaypanel');


      $(prevActivePanel).stop().fadeOut("fast", function() {
        var ithis = $(this);
        ithis.addClass('hidden');
        //console.log('previous Active Panel faded out:' + prevActivePanel);
        $(currentActivePanel)
        .fadeIn("fast", function() {
          history.pushState(null, null, currentActivePanel);
          $(this).removeClass('hidden');
          //console.log('current Active Panel faded in:' + currentActivePanel);
          keywordNav.find('a').removeClass('disabled');

        })

      });

    }

  });
  //check if hash url exists and check an element exists in the DOM that also has the class 'keyword-panel'.
  if (document.location.hash.length > 0 && $(document.location.hash).hasClass('keyword-panel')) {
    // console.log('hash detected:' + document.location.hash);
    $(".js-keyword-navigation li > a[data-displaypanel=" + document.location.hash + "]").trigger('click');
  }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="subjectscontainer panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i>
            Topics
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body keyword-display">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified js-keyword-navigation">
            <li class=""><a href="#" data-displaypanel="#subjectcollection_A_C" class="">A-C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-displaypanel="#subjectcollection_D_H" class="">D-H</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-displaypanel="#subjectcollection_I_N" class="">I-N</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" data-displaypanel="#subjectcollection_O_R" class="">O-R</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-displaypanel="#subjectcollection_S_Z" class="">S-Z</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="topic-blocks list-unstyled">
            <li class="keyword-panel hidden" id="subjectcollection_A_C" style="display: none;">
                <ul class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Acoustics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Acoustics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Agricultural+Economics+%26+Policy&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Agricultural Economics &amp; Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Agricultural+Engineering&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Agricultural Engineering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Agriculture&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Agriculture</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Agriculture%2C+Dairy+%26+Animal+Science&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Agriculture, Dairy &amp; Animal Science</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Agriculture%2C+Multidisciplinary&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Agriculture, Multidisciplinary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Agronomy&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Agronomy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Allergy&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Allergy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Anatomy+%26+Morphology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Anatomy &amp; Morphology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Andrology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Andrology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Anesthesiology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Anesthesiology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Anthropology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Anthropology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Archaeology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Archaeology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Architecture&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Architecture</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Area+Studies&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Area Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Art&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Art</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Arts+%26+Humanities+-+Other+Topics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Arts &amp; Humanities - Other Topics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Asian+Studies&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Asian Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Astronomy+%26+Astrophysics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Astronomy &amp; Astrophysics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Audiology+%26+Speech-Language+Pathology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Audiology &amp; Speech-Language Pathology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Automation+%26+Control+Systems&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Automation &amp; Control Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Behavioral+Sciences&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Behavioral Sciences</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Biochemical+Research+Methods&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Biochemical Research Methods</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Biochemistry+%26+Molecular+Biology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Biochemistry &amp; Molecular Biology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Biodiversity+Conservation&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Biodiversity Conservation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Biodiversity+%26+Conservation&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Biodiversity &amp; Conservation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Biology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Biology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Biomedical+Social+Sciences&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Biomedical Social Sciences</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Biophysics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Biophysics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Biotechnology+%26+Applied+Microbiology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Biotechnology &amp; Applied Microbiology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Business&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Business+%26+Economics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Business &amp; Economics</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Business%2C+Finance&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Business, Finance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Cardiac+%26+Cardiovascular+Systems&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Cardiac &amp; Cardiovascular Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Cardiovascular+System+%26+Cardiology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Cardiovascular System &amp; Cardiology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Cell+Biology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Cell Biology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Cell+%26+Tissue+Engineering&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Cell &amp; Tissue Engineering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Clinical+Neurology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Clinical Neurology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Communication&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Communication</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Computer+Science&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Computer Science</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Computer+Science%2C+Artificial+Intelligence&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Computer Science, Artificial Intelligence</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Computer+Science%2C+Cybernetics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Computer Science, Cybernetics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Computer+Science%2C+Hardware+%26+Architecture&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Computer Science, Hardware &amp; Architecture</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Crystallography&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Crystallography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Cultural+Studies&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Cultural Studies</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="keyword-panel hidden" id="subjectcollection_D_H">
                <ul class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Dance&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Dance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Demography&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Demography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Dentistry%2C+Oral+Surgery+%26+Medicine&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Dentistry, Oral Surgery &amp; Medicine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Dermatology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Dermatology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Developmental+Biology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Developmental Biology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Ecology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Ecology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Engineering%2C+Aerospace&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Engineering, Aerospace</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Engineering%2C+Biomedical&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Engineering, Biomedical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Engineering%2C+Chemical&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Engineering, Chemical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Engineering%2C+Civil&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Engineering, Civil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Engineering%2C+Electrical+%26+Electronic&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Engineering, Electrical &amp; Electronic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Engineering%2C+Environmental&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Engineering, Environmental</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Engineering%2C+Geological&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Engineering, Geological</a></li>
               <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Environmental+Sciences&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Environmental Sciences</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Environmental+Sciences+%26+Ecology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Environmental Sciences &amp; Ecology</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Environmental+Studies&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Environmental Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Ergonomics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Ergonomics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Ethics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Ethics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Ethnic+Studies&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Ethnic Studies</a></li>
               <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Genetics+%26+Heredity&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Genetics &amp; Heredity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Geochemistry+%26+Geophysics&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Geochemistry &amp; Geophysics</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Geography&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Geography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Geography%2C+Physical&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Geography, Physical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Geology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Geology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Geosciences%2C+Multidisciplinary&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Geosciences, Multidisciplinary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Geriatrics+%26+Gerontology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Geriatrics &amp; Gerontology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Gerontology&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Gerontology</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/pub2web/search?value1=Humanities%2C+Multidisciplinary&amp;option1=fulltext" title="">Humanities, Multidisciplinary</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```