# Closure in debounce

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, debouncing

I came across to find out how the debounce works after reading this: 
[Can someone explain the "debounce" function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

In this there was something in the accepted answer that I couldnt figure out how it could be like that:

**"Note that this overwrites the value of timeout and this value persists over multiple function calls!"**

Every time the debounce method is called, it creates a new stack for it, and the returned function could access the timeout value. Yes I understood it as the nature of closure. But across multiple calls, we got  the wrapper debounce will produce a new local timeout, so how can it be possible to clear the timeout in previous calls as they are not bound to the same timeout ?

Thanks a lot, I know this is very basic JS but I do not want to ignore it as I know, if understood it, I can understand more about JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What may be confusing you is that you don't call `debounce()` repeatedly. If you did, then yes, the `timeout` variable would be unique to each invocation.

What you do instead is call `debounce()` *once*. It returns a function which you then can call repeatedly. Because this function is nested inside `debounce()` alongside the `timeout` variable, each time you call it, it uses the same `timeout` variable.

[David Walsh's article](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) has an example:

```
var myEfficientFn = debounce( function() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250 );

window.addEventListener( 'resize', myEfficientFn );
```

Note that we only call `debounce()` once here, and it returns a function which is saved as `myEfficientFn`. Then `myEfficientFn` gets called on every `resize` event, but the callback function passed into `debounce()` is only called after there are no more `resize` events for 250 milliseconds.

You could also write that code equivalently as:

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', debounce( function() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250 ) );
```

Here it may look like you're calling `debounce()` multiple times, but you aren't. It's only being called once, at the time you call `addEventListener()`. The actual event listener function here isn't `debounce()`, it's the function that `debounce()` *returned*.

Or, for more clarity, let's break it apart step by step and use better names:

```
// Called after at least one resize event has fired but 250 milliseconds
// have gone by without another resize event.
function handleResizeAfterIdle() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
}

// Create a function with debouncing that can be used as a resize event
// listener. resizeListener will be called on *every* resize event,
// but handleResizeAfterIdle will be called only after 250 milliseconds
// have elapsed with no more resize events.
var resizeListener = debounce( handleResizeAfterIdle, 250 );

// Now we can add the event listener.
window.addEventListener( 'resize', resizeListener );
```

Comment: But the event handler is set to debounce so every time the event is trigger, let say "click". Everytime I clicked, the debounce will be called again, isnt it ? Because right now I bind the debounce to the event handler.

Comment: Can you add an example of the code you're talking about to the question? I'll take a look at it and see if I can help explain it - or see if you're using `debounce()` correctly. I also added a similar example to the answer.

Comment: @minhtran612: *"Because right now I bind the debounce to the event handler."* that is wrong. You have to bind the function *returned* by `debounce`.

Comment: @MichaelGeary thanks a lot, clearing out the fear that I miss something on closure