# Restrict mulitple request to server, if user perform simultaneous click on list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a help. i was trying to keep track of user clicks. The scenario is, i have list on which user can perform a click, on click a call to server has been made to fetch data. But i get stuck in situation, if user simultaneously click on list, multiple request reached to server.

What i want is only click call will happen and request to server for data.

Here what i've done till now.

```
function getData(id) {
        _this.lastClickId = _this.currentId;
        dataFactory.getListOfData(id).then(function(response) {
            if(_.isEqual(_this.lastClickId , id)){
                appendData(response);
            } else {
                getData(executionId);
            }
        });
        _this.currentId = id;
    }
```

here is my html code:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-click="getData(1)">option1</li>
 <li ng-click="getData(2)">option2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check out the `debounce` technique. This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript

Comment: Another technique is to use the [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive to disable the submit button while the request is in progress.

Comment: Thanx georgeawg, but i can't disable my list. Its user option to select.

Comment: If you want an answer specific to your needs, you need to show how user input connects to the function that performs the HTTP request. Please show the HTML that has the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution will work for you.

You will need to figure out how many clicks you want to allow per second. Let's just say two for know.

```
var clickLimit = 2;
```

You will also need to keep track of the amount of clicks.

```
var clickCount = 0;
```

You are going to have to add 1 to the `clickCount` everytime the user clicks.

Now you can set an interval every second which will remove a click  from the `clickCount`.

```
var clickInterval = setInterval(function () {

    if (clickCount != 0) { clickCount -= 1; }

}, 1000);
```

Then put your code inside of a `if` statement which checks the `clickCount` against the `clickLimit`.

```
if (clickCount <= clickLimit)
{
    // action
}
```

---

Another, and possibily better way to do this, is by using a boolean which would allow the user to click or not. And an interval which would set the boolean to `true` every second or whatever.

Comment: I advise you to change `clickCount != 0` into `clickCount > 0`. If, for some bizarre reason, you end up with `clickCount` being below 0, you can send as many requests as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

### Restrict multiple clicks on input elements

One technique is to use the [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive to disable the submit button while the request is in progress.

```
 <button ng-click="getData(id)" ng-disabled="inProgress">
   Submit
 </button>
```

```
$scope.getData = getData;

function getData(id) {
    $scope.inProgress = true;
    dataFactory.getListOfData(id)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Success");
    }).catch(function(response) }
        console.log("error");
        throw response;
    }).finally(function() {
        $scope.inProgress = false;
    });
}
```

By disabling the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button, multiple clicks will be ignored while the request is in progress.

---

### Restrict multiple clicks on elements other than inputs

For elements other than inputs, the disabled state can be shown with the [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive and by ignoring clicks when disabled:

```
<div ng-click="handleClick(id)" ng-style="inProgress?{opacity:'0.4'}:''">
   Get {{id}}
</div>
```

```
$scope.handleClick = handleClick;

function handleClick(id) {
    if ($scope.inProgress) return;
    $scope.inProgress = true;
    dataFactory.getListOfData(id)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Success");
    }).catch(function(response) }
        console.log("error");
        throw response;
    }).finally(function() {
        $scope.inProgress = false;
    });
}
```

Multiple clicks will be ignored while the request is in progress and the element will be grayed out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't have any submit button, i have a list on user  can perform click.

Comment: If you don't have a submit button, what type of element has the click handler that needs to be inhibited?