# Remove attribute when window is certain size, not on any resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I thought I had solved my problem but now I realize that if I touch the screen to resize it the style tag is removed.  I want it removed only when the width goes below 992,  and then to be replaced if it's greater than 992?

jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth > 992) {
        $(".container").removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

Element it alters:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 240%;">
```

Comment: What a mess. Why don't you use css media queries instead? ↓↓↓

Comment: `@media screen only and (max-width: 992px) { .container { width: 240% }}`

Comment: I have not used this but I will look into it.  Thanks

Comment: This will eliminate the need of a resize event listener.

Comment: Be aware of the fact that CSS and Javascript calculate window width differently depending on the width of the scrollbar (usually a <10px discrepancy, but enough to cause problems if you're using JS and media queries together)

Comment: Great,  I'm pretty sure I can make this work now.  Should this be in the body css?

Comment: Yeah, you can create a style tag or add a .css file with that content.

Comment: @jmgriz  thanks but if this css media queries thing works then I don't think I'll need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest it to use CSS solution.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
 .container {
   width: 240%
 }
}
```

This way you are setting width to container only when screen is bigger then 992px.

If you are because of some reason in a need of js solution. You should:

1. Create a function that check for window width and handle your logic if screen is bigger then 992px
2. Call the function on load/ready event
3. Call the function on resize wrapped in debounce function --> [Can someone explain the "debounce" function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

Comment: do I just add this to the external css file or should it be in the body or something?

Comment: It's CSS. Add it to your other CSS. Or google "media queries tutorial" (but then don't click the w3schools link).

Comment: Cool yea it's not working when I added it but I know this is the correct answer and I just need to learn it a little better.  Thanks.  If I had enough reputation I'd give you guys some points.