# When writing a debounce, what is the point of clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout, debouncing

```
   debounceFunction() {
        let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            doSomething();
            flag = true;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }, 250);
    }
```

I wrote a debounce function that looks like the above, I called this function for several times when an event is triggered. My question is, does the clearTimeout at the end of the *setTimeout* makes any sense?

What would be the optimal way to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `clearTimeout` cancels the adding of this task to event-loop queue, but you need to call it before `setTimeout`

Comment: How about removing the `clearTimeout` call and test it again?

Comment: If it is not to break the `setTimeout` in the execution, it is not necessary to call `clearTimeout` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the clearTimeout at the end of the setTimeout make any sense?

No, there's no point to call `clearTimeout` from within the `setTimeout` callback - it's too late there already. You cannot clear anything, the timeout already occurred.

`clearTimeout` is used when you want to prevent the callback from getting called *before* that would happen.

> What would be the optimal way to do it?

Just omit it.

If you are asking about the optimal way to write `debounce`, see [Can someone explain the "debounce" function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24004791/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, does the clearTimeout at the end of the setTimeout
>   makes any sense?

No, `clearTimeout` is used to clear the previous created timeout, so `clearTimeout` **should be done before `setTimeout` in order to cancel out previous invocation of `setTimeout`**.

> What would be the optimal way to do it?

Have a look [David Walsh's post](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

clearTimeout() prevents the execution of the function that has been set with setTimeout();
In debouncing, a user is made to perform limited actions in a time interval.
So we set that action inside a function within setTimeout and whenever the user tries to perform the same action within the given interval, we call clearTimeout to prevent user from doing it.
So clearTimeout should be called before SetTimeout.