# node.js - in socket callback run my function only once in a minute

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, callback

Let me explain what I am trying to do:

```
 const ws = new WebSocket(url);
        ws.on('message', function (data) {
            //some code
            savetoToDB(result) //this is my function, that i want to be called once in a minute
        });
```

So I making socket connection, and receive data like twice in a second. But i want to execute saveToDB function only once in a minute. How can i achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use something called [debouncing function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) where a function would not be executed more than once in a given time frame.

Here is a link to an [implementation in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript).

Here is a link to the [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce).

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple variable to store the last SaveToDB time would help.

```
const ws = new WebSocket(url);
var savedAt = 0; //Initialization
ws.on('message', function (data) {
   //some code
   var currentTime = Date.now();
   if(currentTime-savedAt>60000){//60000milliseconds
      savetoToDB(result); //this is my function, that i want to be called once in a minute
      savedAt = currentTime;
   }
});
```