# How to delay/start/debounce fetching data until user stops typing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I get enough users on my application, sending an ajax request with each keystroke is an effective way to bring the server to its knees (not to mention possibly making the client application feel quite sluggish). On implementing a symbol search box with two options (DB Search and Web Api Search). While I am typing the symbol (ex: AAPL - aple stock) in the search box the `fetch()` request is sent each time over the network. To avoid it I tried to use `setTimeout()` but `fetch()` request is sent multiple times, anyway. How to delay/start/debounce fetching the request until user stops typing in input area to send only one `fetch()` request?

**HTML:**

```
<label for="symbolTags">Symbol: </label>
  <input type="text" id="symbolTags" name="symbol">

  <label for="api">Select Search Api: </label>
  <select id="api" name="routes_api">
    <option value="search">Web Search Api</option>
    <option value="dbsearch">DB Search Api</option>
  </select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const symbolTags = document.querySelector('#symbolTags')
const symbolTagsOptions = document.querySelector('#api')

const urlsObject = {
  dbsearch: '/dbsearch/',
  search: '/search/'
}

symbolTags.oninput = function () {
  let symbolTagsOptionsValue = symbolTagsOptions.value
  let arg = urlsObject[symbolTagsOptionsValue]

  // Init a timeout variable to be used below
  let timeout = null
  // Clear the timeout if it has already been set.
  // This will prevent the previous task from executing
  // if it has been less than <MILLISECONDS>
  clearTimeout(timeout)
  // Make a new timeout set to go off in 2000ms
  timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    requestSymbolSearch(arg)
  }, 2000)
}

function requestSymbolSearch(arg) {
  getData(arg)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      $('#symbolTags').autocomplete({
        source: data.map(item => item.symbol),
        autoFocus: true
      })
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}

function getData(url) {
  let curValueSymbol = symbolTags.value
  let urlPlus = `${url}${curValueSymbol}`
  console.log(urlPlus)
  return fetchData(urlPlus)
}

async function fetchData(urlPlus) {
  const dataResponse = await fetch(urlPlus)
  const dataJson = await dataResponse.json()
  return dataJson
}
```

**Here is the console result:**

[image: fetch result]

**Here is the network result:**

[image]

Comment: how about using minimum input length, For example `fetch` request will be made only after n number of characters entered in the input

Comment: @brk the problem that it could be one letter symbol as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is commonly solved by *[debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)* the event; which collapses **multiple calls** in a given timeframe to **just one**:

```js
// Debounce function from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24004791/1814486
const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
  let timeout

  return function() {
    const context = this, args = arguments
    const later = function() {
      timeout = null
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args)
    }

    const callNow = immediate && !timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args)
  }
}
  
// If there's not another `input` within 500ms log the value,
// otherwise ignore the event.
document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('input', debounce(() => {
  console.log(input.value)
}, 500))
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Type fast here.."/>
```

Comment: `keyup` event is working well but i am trying to implement `oninput` event for some reason it does not work

Comment: What is `symbolTabs`? Is it an `<input>` element?

Comment: just added HTML to the question

Comment: @JohnJohn Edited.