# Fixing the Mobile Double-Click Link Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im setting up a onclick dropdown navigation bar for the mobile part of my website, The problem im having is when it takes a double click in order for it to drop down. The result I want is for it to drop down on the first click.

The only thing I've tried so far is a Javascript function that I will show in my code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("submenu1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
    }

function myFunction_2() {
  var y = document.getElementById("submenu2");
  if (y.style.display === "none") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#submenu1 .submenu1-li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav a {
  display: flex;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5% 0%;
}

.submenu1-li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#submenu1 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.submenu2-li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#submenu2 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#submenu2 .submenu2-li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

#active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
}

#submenu1 a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
 #desktop-port-move:hover #submenu2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="hide" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()">Menu
            <span class="arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
          </a>
            <ul id="submenu1">
              <li class="submenu1-li">
                <a id="active" href="home.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="submenu1-li">
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
              </li>
              <li id="desktop-contact-move" class="submenu1-li" >
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li id="desktop-port-move" class="submenu1-li" style:"order: 1;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction_2();">Portfolio
                  <span class="arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
                </a>
                <ul id="submenu2">
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="designs.html">Designs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="websites.html">Websites</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

I expect the output to be a dropdown menu that responds on first click.
but the output im getting is a dropdown menu that responds on the second click, which is wrong for what I want.

Thanks in advance
and blessings to those who help

Comment: When you need is a "debounce" function. This ignores additional clicks during a timeout.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not showing on the first click is that this condition

```
if (x.style.display === "none")
```

is false since you've set  `display: none;` in CSS stylesheet. So a really quick way to fix this would be to add `display: none;` inline:

```
<ul id="submenu1" style="display:none;">
```

But a cleaner way would be to use classes to control menu visibility. See the snippet below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("submenu1");
  x.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#submenu1 .submenu1-li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav a {
  display: flex;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5% 0%;
}

.submenu1-li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#submenu1 {
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#submenu1.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.submenu2-li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#submenu2 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#submenu2 .submenu2-li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

#active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
}

#submenu1 a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
 #desktop-port-move:hover #submenu2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="hide" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()">Menu
            <span class="arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
          </a>
            <ul id="submenu1" class="hidden">
              <li class="submenu1-li">
                <a id="active" href="home.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="submenu1-li">
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
              </li>
              <li id="desktop-contact-move" class="submenu1-li" >
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li id="desktop-port-move" class="submenu1-li" style:"order: 1;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction_2();">Portfolio
                  <span class="arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
                </a>
                <ul id="submenu2">
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="designs.html">Designs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="websites.html">Websites</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here the problem is that the `x.style.display` returns blank string because that property is defined in stylesheet.

1st solution is to use inline css

2nd is apply another check for blank string like this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("submenu1");
  if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
    }

function myFunction_2() {
  var y = document.getElementById("submenu2");
  if (y.style.display === "none" || y.style.display === "") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#submenu1 .submenu1-li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav a {
  display: flex;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5% 0%;
}

.submenu1-li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#submenu1 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.submenu2-li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#submenu2 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#submenu2 .submenu2-li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

#active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
}

#submenu1 a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
 #desktop-port-move:hover #submenu2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="hide" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()">Menu
            <span class="arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
          </a>
            <ul id="submenu1">
              <li class="submenu1-li">
                <a id="active" href="home.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="submenu1-li">
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
              </li>
              <li id="desktop-contact-move" class="submenu1-li" >
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li id="desktop-port-move" class="submenu1-li" style:"order: 1;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction_2();">Portfolio
                  <span class="arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
                </a>
                <ul id="submenu2">
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="designs.html">Designs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="websites.html">Websites</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu2-li">
                    <a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

More information about the problem at : [Fixing the Mobile Double-Click Link Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468557/fixing-the-mobile-double-click-link-issue)