# How to get the element in the DOM children array that returns in getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Is there any way to detect the elements in proxy object that is returned from getElementsByTagName() ? I need to addEventListener to the returned svgs from below code

```
const svgs= document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
console.log('svgs',svgs);
const myArray = Array.from(svgs); 
console.log('myArray ',myArray); // This is returning []
```

Below is the log that i can see in console . Can some one help me to get the svgs=>target=>HTMLCollection(49) into array
[image]

Comment: https://jsbin.com/cayegesefi/1/edit?html,js,console — I can't reproduce the problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This looks like an asynchrony issue. The `svgs` object is a *live* collection, and your console is showing the content as it is at a later time (when you click to open the structure in the console), while the array reflects the state at the very moment of logging.

Comment: Possibly dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that these `svg` elements are apparently added to the document asynchronously. By the time you look at the console and open the `svgs` structure, the `svg` elements have been loaded, but this was not the case yet at the moment your code ran and created the array. That you see them is because of [the console's lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays).

If the `svg` elements are loaded on page load, then you might be lucky and you can just wrap your code in something like:

```
window.onload = () => { /* your code */ }
```

But it is more likely that this content is loaded via some Ajax calls, and then the above wont help.

You could listen to DOM mutation events:

```
const svgs = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
console.log(svgs.length); // <-- presumably outputs 0

const listener = new MutationObserver(updated);
// This listens to changes under the BODY element. If you can be more 
// precise, then do so (to save resources). If you can do without
// the subtree option, then that is also preferred:
listener.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

function updated() {
    console.log(svgs.length); // <-- notice the increased length
    // Do whatever else you want to do with this collection.

    // If you are sure you have all you need, then stop the listener:
    listener.disconnect();
}
```

If the elements are populated all "at once", and you just want one call of the event listener, then you may still need to tune it with some [debouncing pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript).