# Vuejs & Axios make multiple get requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a simple Vue script, learning Vue for the first time:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="watch-example">
      <p>
          Ask a yes/no question:
          <input v-model="question" type="text">
          <img v-bind:src="image">
      </p>
      <p>{{ answer }}</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    let watchExample = new Vue({

        // Root element of app
        el   : '#watch-example',

        // Properties keep track of
        data : {
            question : '',
            answer   : 'I cannot give you an answer until you ask a question!',
            image    : '',
        },
        watch : {
            question : function(newVal, oldVal) {
                const vm  = this;
                vm.answer = 'Waitinng for you to stop typing.';

                setTimeout(function() {
                    vm.getAnswer();
                }, 350);
            }
        },

        // App methods
        methods : {
            getAnswer: function() {
                const vm = this;

                if(!vm.question.includes('?')) {
                    vm.answer = 'Questions usually contain a question mark';
                    vm.image  = '';
                    return;
                }
                vm.answer = 'Thinking...';

                setTimeout(function() {
                    axios.get('https://yesno.wtf/api')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            vm.answer = response.data.answer;
                            vm.image  = response.data.image;
                        });
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed that when I type a question, containing a question mark(`?`) too fast, it makes multiple requests, and I get multiple responses. It clears out images upon multiple returned responses and adds new ones. If I type a question slowly, only one response is returned.

`console.log(response)` shows the multiple responses in the console.

How can I make only one request to get one response to a question no matter the typing speed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain the "debounce" function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just restart the timer on every change (i.e., stop the current timer if any, and then start another timer). Note that [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns its associated timer ID, which you could pass to [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to stop the timer. Your code should look similar to this:

```js
watch: {
    question : function(newVal, oldVal) {
        ...

        clearTimeout(this._timerId);
        this._timerId = setTimeout(function() {
            vm.getAnswer();
        }, 350);
    }
},
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="watch-example">
      <p>
          Ask a yes/no question:
          <input v-model="question" type="text">
          <img v-bind:src="image">
      </p>
      <p>{{ answer }}</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    let watchExample = new Vue({

        // Root element of app
        el   : '#watch-example',

        // Properties keep track of
        data : {
            question : '',
            answer   : 'I cannot give you an answer until you ask a question!',
            image    : '',
        },
        watch : {
            question : function(newVal, oldVal) {
                const vm  = this;
                vm.answer = 'Waitinng for you to stop typing.';

                clearTimeout(this._timerId);
                this._timerId = setTimeout(function() {
                    vm.getAnswer();
                }, 350);
            }
        },

        // App methods
        methods : {
            getAnswer: function() {
                const vm = this;

                if(!vm.question.includes('?')) {
                    vm.answer = 'Questions usually contain a question mark';
                    vm.image  = '';
                    return;
                }
                vm.answer = 'Thinking...';

                setTimeout(function() {
                    axios.get('https://yesno.wtf/api')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            vm.answer = response.data.answer;
                            vm.image  = response.data.image;
                        });
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks! @tony19

Comment: @RobertRocha No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is `debounce` from `lodash`

A good example was given in the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Pay attention to this particular code, as an example:

```
created: function () {
    // _.debounce is a function provided by lodash to limit how
    // often a particularly expensive operation can be run.
    // In this case, we want to limit how often we access
    // yesno.wtf/api, waiting until the user has completely
    // finished typing before making the ajax request. To learn
    // more about the _.debounce function (and its cousin
    // _.throttle), visit: https://lodash.com/docs#debounce
    this.debouncedGetAnswer = _.debounce(this.getAnswer, 500)
  },
```

Comment: Am trying to do it without using that though

Comment: It will be hard to achieve it with a good performance. You have to do with the `question.length > X characters`

Answer (score 1):

Currently your are just delaying your call by wrapping it in a setTimeout. I think you're trying to accomplish a `debounce` effect.

Lodash has this function but if you don't already use lodash and don't want to include it in your project you could easily write it yourself in a few lines of code.