# How to stop rapid clicks from breaking my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css grid. 
When you click a div, it will toggle a class that makes it expand, then after 3000ms, 
the class is toggled again and the div collpases back to original size. 
The user should be able to over-ride this delay, so that if they want to collapse the div before the 3s setTimeout has elapsed, they can do it.

My issue is that when this happens, it doesn't cancel the set timeout function, 
and then the user input and the old 'lagging' code begin to overlap, 
which creates a mess and breaks my logic.

heres the code:

```
var open = false;

function dissolveExpand(parent, sibling, tte){
    if(open==false){
        open=true;
        toggle(parent, sibling, tte);
    } else{
        open=false;
        toggle(parent, sibling, tte);
    };
};

function closer(parent, sibling, tte){
    if(open==true){
        toggle(parent, sibling, tte);
    };
    console.log(open);
};

function toggle(parent, sibling, tte){
    parent.classList.toggle("expanded-div");
    sibling.classList.toggle("hidden-div");
    tte.classList.toggle("expanded-tap");
};

tte_parent1.onclick = function(){
    dissolveExpand(tte_parent1, sibling1, tte1);
    setTimeout(function(){closer(tte_parent1, sibling1, tte1); }, 3000);

};`
```

If I sit here and spam click the tte_parent element, the code just stops working 
properly.

Sorry for the lack of specifics but I'm stuck

Comment: Might need to implement a [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The `clearTimeout()` method clears a timer set with the `setTimeout()`. And instead of apply a `true` or false to the `open` variable, i would use`isOpen = false` , then `isOpen = !isOpen` every time it clicked

```
let isOpen = false;
let timeOut;

toggleClassList(){ 
  if(isOpen) {
     isOpen = !isOpen 
     //Remove expand class list logics 
     clearTimeOut(timeOut)
     return;
  } 
  isOpen = !isOpen 
  //Add expand class list logics go here
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
       isOpen = !isOpen
       //Remove class list after 3s
  }, 3000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is assign the `setTimeout()` call to a variable, because using `setTimeout()` returns a number unique to that call (like an id) which you can use to identify the timeout call when you want to clear it with `clearTimeout()`, an example below:

```
let timeOut = setTimeout(()=>console.log('this is a timeout'),3000);

clearTimeout(timeOut); // this cancels the timeout
```