# Change layer z-index in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to trace underground pipes which I create using the polyline methods.

Since the pipes/lines can sometimes overlap I need to be able to highlight the selected line which requires switching the z-index of the line.

Now it seems that leaflet does offer a setZIndex method, but it's not available for individual layers - so I can change it over an entire featureGroup, but that is less helfpul - and making every line into its own separate featureGroup feels like an overkill.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#path-bringtofront

Answer (score 0):

You could create another layer with a superior z-index that would be empty at start. When the mouse is going over a feature, copy the feature into that layer. When the mouse is going out, just remove it from the layer.

It might be a little bit cpu demanding, so I suggest you to [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript) the mouseover function in order to make the mouse to wait 1-2 seconds over a feature before copying it into the top layer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's a better solution than creating separate featureGroups. I assume that means that there is no built in support for layer Z-index?

Comment: maybe map pane is what you are looking for: https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Answer (score 0):

As IvanSanchez noted in a comment, the correct answer seems to be a method called bringToFront.