# How to do something once chrome extension popup is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension which has a form where I take notes.

Say I'm reading Wikipedia. Whilst reading I want to open the extension popup, paste/write something, close the popup, read some more, open the popup, past/write some more.

At the end, I'd hit submit and send the data to API.

Every time the popup closes though the data on the form is gone. So I thought, on popup closing, I'd add the data to local storage (**not sure if there's another way**)

So I'm trying to use the background script.

In the manifest file

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
```

And in the `background.js`

```
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(externalPort) {
   externalPort.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
      console.log("onDisconnect - nothing logs");
      localStorage.setItem("test", "test");
   });
   console.log("onConnect - nothing logs");
});
console.log("this logs")
```

That doesn't work. All the research led me to `chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener` but there's no response at all, (the `background.js` is linked correctly)

Comment: I believe extensions have access to their own storage API: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: The correct approach is to save the pasted data immediately in a listener for `input` event because when the popup is closed its environment is destroyed so fast you won't have time. Also, there's nothing wrong with using HTML5 `localStorage` for saving small strings.

Comment: @wOxxOm isn't that "expensive", on keyup do the operation? Or is there no such thing as expensive in this case? (I don't want to do it on button click)

Comment: It's not expensive unless you're running on a 30-year old CPU, but anyway whenever a performance-related concern arises you should always check first using the excellent performance profiler and other modern tools. Also, you can use **debouncing**.

Comment: Re the last part, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript).