# Lag on passing AJAX data to PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create an ajax search. I tried creating a fast loading php and another php pagecontaining the search form.

Search form:

`<input id="searchtop" type="text" class="search-field" onkeyup="searchNotes()">`

Search PHP link sample:

`/searchform/?key=string`

The `searchNotes()` JS function:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) {
        func.apply(context, args);
      }
    }, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  }
}

function searchNotes() {

  var searcher = document.getElementById("searchtop").value;
if (searcher.length > 3) {
 currentRequest = jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/searchform/?key='+searcher,
                   cache: false,

     success: function(data) {
             $("#datafetch").html(data);
     }
 })};

}

var debounced = debounce(searchNotes, 50);

window.addEventListener('keyup', debounced);
```

issue: When I try typing for example "smooth" on the input fast, it works fine at first but then it loads all "smoot", "smoo", etc over the main "smooth" result and "smooth" is removed by `jQuery('#datafetch').html('');` by the other incomplete strings.

I wanted to find a way to get the last string that is typed on input whithout the issue.

Comment: look into *debounce* and you only need `$("#datafetch").html(data);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone may I ask for the long answer with _debounce_?

Comment: Sure, [Can someone explain the debounce function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so I did it and it almost works,Thanks for that!
But it shows the incomplete string results again for 1-2 seconds and then it fixes itself. any idea about that?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just found the answer. 1 and 2 letter searchs were buggy and they replaced the main string. I just made a condition that ```searcher.length > 3```
Thanks so much for the help ;)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone oh still that's buggy. I'll update my code edit: updated

Comment: 50ms is too short, experiment with the value, it should be more like 300, then it will wait a bit longer between characters, your target wait value is a slow typer, like my nan

Comment: @LawrenceCherone even if I put it on 500ms, after typing something like "smooth criminal" it changes the output to "smooth criminal" results at the moment and after a second or two, it changes to something like "smooth cri".

Answer (score 0):

OK this was my way to fix this:

```
var searchInput = $("#searchtop");
var searchQueryDisplay = $("#datafetch");

var showSearchQuery = function() {

      var searcher = document.getElementById("searchtop").value;
    if (searcher.length > 3) {

     currentRequest = jQuery.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/searchform/?key='+searcher,
                       cache: false,

         success: function(data) {
                 $("#datafetch").html(data);
         }
     })};

    }


var debounceTimeout = null;
searchInput.on('change keyup', function(event){
  clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
  debounceTimeout = setTimeout(showSearchQuery, 300);
});
```