# optimize search method to reduce API requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I built a basic search function to get real-time search results from backend. The flow is basically like this

1 - watch search input, if length > 2 then send the changes a query to backend and fetch the results in the table.

```
watch:{
search(val,old){
  if (val.length >= 2 || old.length >= 2){
    this.setList({url:`/customer/my-bag/global-filter`, query_value:val}).then((res) =>{
      this.pagination.lastPage = res.data.meta.last_page
    })
```

2 - If the search input is `''` then get all customers paginate them in 5 pages.

```
 if (this.search === ''){
    this.loadCustomers()
  }
```

`SetList` is a method in the store to get the result from API

```
methods: {
...mapActions("users", ["setList"]),
```

**Result**

Too many API requests for one search query ( around 40 requests). My goal is to make the search way better in terms of requests and "correct" method.

Comment: Instead on each input value change doing a request, you could wait a few moments until there are no changes anymore and then do the request.

Comment: Try debounce, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24004942/14144301

Comment: One way to decrease this number of requests is to use the debounce technique

Comment: hmm debounce sounds great but it would slow the process of "real-time" feature

Comment: @AlmoDev while technically true, it is generally imperceptible to users as debounce's **wait** time is in milliseconds. Say you type 6 chars a second, your current method makes 6 requests, if you use `debounce` with a wait of **500 milliseconds**, you reduce the number of requests by half. You can play with the **wait** value, to satisfy yourself it is responsive enough, but it will always be a trade off between number of requests vs perceived real-time responsiveness.

Comment: Thank you for all your answer. I will do a denounce request