# How do I implement debounce in ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, debouncing

I am pretty sure the answer is that it is not possible, but I was wondering if it is possible to implement `lodash.debounce` using Ramda so I can get rid of the `lodash` dependency in my app since it's down to just that.

This is the code I am using

```
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";
import { Dispatch, useCallback, useState } from "react";


/**
 * This is a variant of set state that debounces rapid changes to a state.
 * This perform a shallow state check, use {@link useDebouncedDeepState}
 * for a deep comparison.  Internally this uses
 * [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) to perform
 * the debounce operation.
 * @param initialValue initial value
 * @param wait debounce wait
 * @param debounceSettings debounce settings.
 * @returns state and setter
 *
 */
export function useDebouncedState<S>(
  initialValue: S,
  wait: number,
  debounceSettings?: Parameters<typeof debounce>[2]
): [S, Dispatch<S>] {
  const [state, setState] = useState<S>(initialValue);
  const debouncedSetState = useCallback(
    debounce(setState, wait, debounceSettings),
    [wait, debounceSettings]
  );
  useEffect(()=> {
    return () => debouncedSetState.cancel();
  }, []);
  return [state, debouncedSetState];
}
```

Comment: Why not just use plain JavaScript? [Can someone explain the "debounce" function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24004791) In what way is Ramda really useful for implementing this pretty standard and well-known function?

Comment: the example provided doesn't have the nuances that lodash.debounce does.  One of which is cancelation semantics which I just noticed my code does not use and would explain bug I had where there was a state change when the component was unmounted.

Comment: I still fail to see how Ramda is relevant to implementing debouncing, though. If you want cancellation, that's still nothing to do with another library. As you can see, debounding just has two really relevant components - delay (which you don't need a library for) and calling a function by preserving `this` (which is also something you don't need a library for). A cancellation mechanic is an extra `if` in the delay to decide whether to fire the delayed function. For which of these tasks do you want to use Ramda?

Comment: Ramda does not include anything like `debounce` as it doesn't really seem to sit well with Ramda's philosophy.  (Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda founder.)  But as VLAZ says, it's not difficult to create your own.  I doubt Ramda functions would help much with doing that, but you never know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**debounce without cancellation**

VLAZ linked [Can someone explain the "debounce" function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24004791) but you seem disappointed and looking for something with a cancellation mechanism. The answer I provided to that question implements a vanilla `debounce` that -

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| ✅ | At most one promise pending at any given time (per debounced task) |
| ✅ | Stop memory leaks by properly cancelling pending promises |
| ✅ | Resolve only the latest promise |
| ❌ | Expose cancellation mechanism |

We wrote `debounce` with two parameters, the `task` to debounce, and the amount of milliseconds to delay, `ms`. We introduced a single local binding for its local state, `t` -

```js
// original implementation
function debounce(task, ms) {
  let t = { promise: null, cancel: _ => void 0 }
  return async (...args) => { // ⚠️ does not return cancel mechanism
    try {
      t.cancel()
      t = deferred(ms)
      await t.promise
      await task(...args)
    }
    catch (_) { /* prevent memory leak */ }
  }
}
```

```js
// original usage
// ⚠️ how to cancel?
myform.mybutton.addEventListener("click", debounce(clickCounter, 1000))
```

**now with external cancellation**

The original code is approachable in size, less than 10 lines, and is intended for you to tinker with to meet your specific needs. We can expose the cancellation mechanism by simply including it with the other returned value -

```js
// revised implementation
function debounce(task, ms) {
  let t = { promise: null, cancel: _ => void 0 }
  return [
    async (...args) => { 
      try {
        t.cancel()
        t = deferred(ms)
        await t.promise
        await task(...args)
      }
      catch (_) { /* prevent memory leak */ }
    },
    _ => t.cancel() // ✅ return cancellation mechanism
  ]
}
```

```js
// revised usage
const [inc, cancel] = debounce(clickCounter, 1000) // ✅ two controls
myform.mybutton.addEventListener("click", inc)
myform.mycancel.addEventListener("click", cancel)
```

**deferred**

`debounce` depends on a reusable `deferred` function, which creates a new promise that resolves in `ms` milliseconds. Read more about it in the linked Q&A -

```js
function deferred(ms) {
  let cancel, promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cancel = reject
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
  return { promise, cancel }
}
```

**demo with cancellation**

Run the snippet below. The <kbd>Click</kbd> is debounced for one (1) second. After the debounce timer expires, the counter is incremented. However, if you click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> while `inc` is debounced, the pending function will be cancelled and the counter will not be incremented.

```js
// debounce, compressed for demo
function debounce(task, ms) {
  let t = { promise: null, cancel: _ => void 0 }
  return [ async (...args) => { try { t.cancel(); t = deferred(ms); await t.promise; await task(...args) } catch (_) { /* prevent memory leak */ } }, _ => t.cancel() ]
}

// deferred, compressed for demo
function deferred(ms) {
  let cancel, promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { cancel = reject; setTimeout(resolve, ms) }); return { promise, cancel }
}

// dom references
const myform = document.forms.myform
const mycounter = myform.mycounter

// event handler
function clickCounter (event) {
  mycounter.value = Number(mycounter.value) + 1
}

// debounced listener
[inc, cancel] = debounce(clickCounter, 1000)
myform.myclicker.addEventListener("click", inc)
myform.mycancel.addEventListener("click", cancel)
```

```html
<form id="myform">
<input name="myclicker" type="button" value="click" />
<input name="mycancel" type="button" value="cancel" />
<output name="mycounter">0</output>
</form>
```

**types**

Some sensible annotations for `deferred` and `debounce`, for the people thinking about types.

```js
// cancel : () -> void
// 
// waiting : {
//   promise: void promise,
//   cancel: cancel
// }
//
// deferred : int -> waiting
function deferred(ms) {
  let cancel, promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cancel = reject
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
  return { promise, cancel }
}
```

```js
// 'a task : (...any -> 'a)
//
// debounce : ('a task, int) -> ('a task, cancel)
function debounce(task, ms) {
  let t = { promise: null, cancel: _ => void 0 }
  return [
    async (...args) => { 
      try {
        t.cancel()
        t = deferred(ms)
        await t.promise
        await task(...args)
      }
      catch (_) { /* prevent memory leak */ }
    },
    _ => t.cancel()
  ]
}
```

**react hook**

Implementing `useDebounce` with `debounce` is super easy. Remember to `cancel` when the component is unmounted to prevent any dangling debounced operations -

```js
function useDebounce(task, ms) {
  const [f, cancel] = debounce(task, ms)
  useEffect(_ => cancel) // ✅ auto-cancel when component unmounts
  return [f, cancel]
}
```

Add `useDebounce` to your component is the same way we used vanilla `debounce` above. If debouncing state mutations, make sure to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) as setter will be called asynchronously -

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [inc, cancel] = useDebounce(
    _ => setCount(x => x + 1), // ✅ functional update
    1000
  )
  return <div>
    <button onClick={inc}>click</button>
    <button onClick={cancel}>cancel</button>
    <span>{count}</span>
  </div>
}
```

**react debounce demo**

This demo is the same as the only above, only use React and our `useDebounce` hook -

```js
// debounce, compressed for demo
function debounce(task, ms) {
  let t = { promise: null, cancel: _ => void 0 }
  return [ (...args) => { t.cancel(); t = deferred(ms); t.promise.then(_ => task(...args)).catch(_ => {}) }, _ => t.cancel() ]
}

// deferred, compressed for demo
function deferred(ms) {
  let cancel, promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { cancel = reject; setTimeout(resolve, ms) }); return { promise, cancel }
}

function useDebounce(task, ms) {
  const [f, cancel] = debounce(task, ms)
  React.useEffect(_ => cancel)
  return [f, cancel]
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [inc, cancel] = useDebounce(
    _ => setCount(x => x + 1),
    1000
  )
  return <div>
    <button onClick={inc}>click</button>
    <button onClick={cancel}>cancel</button>
    <span>{count}</span>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**multiple debounces**

Let's double-check everything is correct and show multiple debounces being used on the same page. We'll extend the counter example by adding more <kbd>Click</kbd> buttons that call the same debounced function. And we'll put multiple counters on the same page to show that multiple debouncers maintain individual control and don't interrupt other debouncers. Here's a preview of the app -

[image: multiple-debounces-preview]

Run the demo and verify each of these behaviours -

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| ✅ | 3 Counters, each with their own counter state |
| ✅ | Each counter has 3 debounced <kbd>Click</kbd> buttons and a single <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button |
| ✅ | Each <kbd>Click</kbd> can be used to increment the counter's value |
| ✅ | Each <kbd>Click</kbd> will interrupt any debounced increment from other <kbd>Click</kbd> belonging to that counter |
| ✅ | The <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button will cancel debounced increments from any <kbd>Click</kbd> belonging to that counter |
| ✅ | <kbd>Cancel</kbd> will not cancel debounced increments belonging to other counters |

```js
function debounce(task, ms) { let t = { promise: null, cancel: _ => void 0 }; return [ (...args) => { t.cancel(); t = deferred(ms); t.promise.then(_ => task(...args)).catch(_ => {}) }, _ => t.cancel() ] }
function deferred(ms) { let cancel, promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { cancel = reject; setTimeout(resolve, ms) }); return { promise, cancel } }
function useDebounce(task, ms) {const [f, cancel] = debounce(task, ms); React.useEffect(_ => cancel); return [f, cancel] }

function useCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [inc, cancel] = useDebounce(
    _ => setCount(x => x + 1),
    1000
  )
  return [count, <div className="counter">
    <button onClick={inc}>click</button>
    <button onClick={inc}>click</button>
    <button onClick={inc}>click</button>
    <button onClick={cancel}>cancel</button>
    <span>{count}</span>
  </div>]
}

function App() {
  const [a, counterA] = useCounter()
  const [b, counterB] = useCounter()
  const [c, counterC] = useCounter()
  return <div>
    {counterA}
    {counterB}
    {counterC}
    <pre>Total: {a+b+c}</pre>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.counter { padding: 0.5rem; margin-top: 0.5rem; background-color: #ccf; }
pre { padding: 0.5rem; background-color: #ffc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: really well and extensively explained Debounce answer.