# Lexicaljs receive editor state json and text content using debounce in react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lexicaljs

### Requirement

I have a requirement to get the editor state in JSON format as well as the text content of the editor. In addition, I want to receive these values in the [debounced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791) way.

I wanted to get these values (as debounced) because I wanted to send them to my server.

### Dependencies

`"react": "^18.2.0",`

`"lexical": "^0.3.8",`

`"@lexical/react": "^0.3.8",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to touch any of Lexical's internals for this; a custom hook that reads and "stashes" the editor state into a ref and sets up a debounced callback ([via `use-debounce` here, but you can use whatever implementation you like](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce)) is enough.

- `getEditorState` is in charge of converting the editor state into whichever format you want to send over the wire. It's always called within `editorState.read()`.

```
function useDebouncedLexicalOnChange<T>(
  getEditorState: (editorState: EditorState) => T,
  callback: (value: T) => void,
  delay: number
) {
  const lastPayloadRef = React.useRef<T | null>(null);
  const callbackRef = React.useRef<(arg: T) => void | null>(callback);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);
  const callCallbackWithLastPayload = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (lastPayloadRef.current) {
      callbackRef.current?.(lastPayloadRef.current);
    }
  }, []);
  const call = useDebouncedCallback(callCallbackWithLastPayload, delay);
  const onChange = React.useCallback(
    (editorState) => {
      editorState.read(() => {
        lastPayloadRef.current = getEditorState(editorState);
        call();
      });
    },
    [call, getEditorState]
  );
  return onChange;
}

// ...

const getEditorState = (editorState: EditorState) => ({
  text: $getRoot().getTextContent(false),
  stateJson: JSON.stringify(editorState)
});

function App() {
  const debouncedOnChange = React.useCallback((value) => {
    console.log(new Date(), value);
    // TODO: send to server
  }, []);
  const onChange = useDebouncedLexicalOnChange(
    getEditorState,
    debouncedOnChange,
    1000
  );
  // ...
  <OnChangePlugin onChange={onChange} /> 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Code

File: onChangeDebouce.tsx

```
import {$getRoot} from "lexical";
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from "@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext";
import React from "react";

const CAN_USE_DOM = typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.document !== 'undefined' && typeof window.document.createElement !== 'undefined';

const useLayoutEffectImpl = CAN_USE_DOM ? React.useLayoutEffect : React.useEffect;
var useLayoutEffect = useLayoutEffectImpl;
type onChangeFunction = (editorStateJson: string, editorText: string) => void;

export const OnChangeDebounce: React.FC<{
    ignoreInitialChange?: boolean;
    ignoreSelectionChange?: boolean;
    onChange: onChangeFunction;
    wait?: number
}> = ({ ignoreInitialChange= true, ignoreSelectionChange = false, onChange, wait= 167 }) => {

    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
    let timerId:  NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        return editor.registerUpdateListener(({
                                                  editorState,
                                                  dirtyElements,
                                                  dirtyLeaves,
                                                  prevEditorState
                                              }) => {
            if (ignoreSelectionChange && dirtyElements.size === 0 && dirtyLeaves.size === 0) {
                return;
            }

            if (ignoreInitialChange && prevEditorState.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            if(timerId === null) {
              timerId = setTimeout(() => {
                editorState.read(() => {
                  const root = $getRoot();
                  onChange(JSON.stringify(editorState), root.getTextContent());
                })
              }, wait);
            } else {
              clearTimeout(timerId);
              timerId = setTimeout(() => {
                editorState.read(() => {
                  const root = $getRoot();
                  onChange(JSON.stringify(editorState), root.getTextContent());
                });
              }, wait);
            }
        });
    }, [editor, ignoreInitialChange, ignoreSelectionChange, onChange]);

    return null;
}
```

This is the code for the plugin and it is inspired (or copied) from `OnChangePlugin` of lexical
Since, lexical is in early development the implementation of `OnChangePlugin` might change. And in fact, there is one more parameter added as of version 0.3.8. You can check the latest code at [github](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/blob/main/packages/lexical-react/src/LexicalOnChangePlugin.ts).

The only thing I have added is calling onChange function in timer logic.

ie.

```
if(timerId === null) {
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      editorState.read(() => {
        const root = $getRoot();
        onChange(JSON.stringify(editorState), root.getTextContent());
      })
    }, wait);
} else {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(() => {
    editorState.read(() => {
      const root = $getRoot();
      onChange(JSON.stringify(editorState), root.getTextContent());
    });
  }, wait);
}
```

If you are new to lexical, then you have to use declare this plugin as a child of lexical composer, something like this.

File: RichEditor.tsx

```
<LexicalComposer initialConfig={getRichTextConfig(namespace)}>
    <div className="editor-shell lg:m-2" ref={scrollRef}>
      <div className="editor-container">
        {/* your other plugins */}
        <RichTextPlugin
          contentEditable={<ContentEditable
            className={"ContentEditable__root"} />
          }
          placeholder={<Placeholder text={placeHolderText} />}
        />
        <OnChangeDebounce onChange={onChange} />
      </div>
    </div>
</LexicalComposer>
```

In this code, as you can see I have passed the onChange function as a prop and you can also pass `wait`  in milliseconds like this.

```
<OnChangeDebounce onChange={onChange} wait={1000}/>
```

Now the last bit is the implementation of onChange function, which is pretty straightforward

```
const onChange = (editorStateJson:string, editorText:string) => {

  console.log("editorStateJson:", editorStateJson);
  console.log("editorText:", editorText);
    // send data to a server or to your data store (eg. redux)
};
```

### Finally

Thanks to Meta and the lexical team for open sourcing this library. And lastly, the code I have provided works for me, I am no expert, feel free to comment to suggest an improvement.