# How debounce function return the function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this debounce function:

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('input');

const debounce = (cb, time = 1000) => {
  let timer;

  return (...args) => {
    console.log('run inner function')
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }
    timer = setTimeout(() => cb(...args), time)
  }
}

const onChange = debounce((e) => {
  console.log('event', e.target.value)
})
selectElement.addEventListener('input', onChange);
```

```html
<input input={onChange}/>
```

The code works ok, but I want to understand, how the returned function is triggered inside `debounce` function, because I know that if a function returns another function I need to call it like this: `debounce()()` to trigger the second one, but in our case we trigger the function only once `debounce()` in `addEventListener`, but how the second call happens?

Comment: You call `debounce(...)` once to create `onChange`. Then the event listener calls `onChange()` upon `input`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "debounce" function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/what-is-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Even though it’s basically the same thing and will not cause an error, you should try to use setTimeout with clearTimeout and setInterval with clearInterval so people who look at your code are not confused.

Comment: @James, fixed, it was it was't intentionally. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it would help to first acknowledge that:

```
debounce()();
```

can be rewritten as

```
let onChange = debounce();
onChange();
```

And you've passed `onChange` to `addEventListener` here:

```
selectElement.addEventListener('input', onChange);
```

The internals of the event listener mechanism will remember the `onChange` you passed in and will call `onChange()` when the `input` event occurs.

Imagine an implementation of `function addEventListener(type, listener) {}` that arranges for `listener()` to happen when the event occurs.

This is done to *defer* the function call.  The first part (`debounce()`) creates a function immediately (synchronously).  But the call to the function that `debounce()` returned is deferred until the event occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You only would call it like `debounce()()` if you want to immediately call the function it returns (and throw away the entire point, since with that method you could only call it once).

It returns a function, which here you've named `onChange`. `onChange` is called when the `selectElement` has a `input` event. You don't say `selectElement.addEventListener(('input', onChange())` (emphasis on `onChange()`) because that would just call `onChange` once (immediately, not even on the first `input` event) and attempt to run a function returned from onChange, but it doesn't