# p5.js sketch crashes after making window larger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

This is my code:

```
// A Perlin Noise Flow Feild
import 'react'
import Sketch from 'react-p5'
import "../../App.css"

const Flow = () => {
    let w, h, nums;
    let density = 0.005
    let zOff = 0;
    let scl = 0.001;
    let speed = 12;
    let particles = []

    const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
        // Sets initial conditions
        w = p5.windowWidth
        h = p5.windowHeight
        nums = Math.ceil((w + h) / 1.5)
        p5.frameRate(30)
        p5.createCanvas(w, h, p5.WEBGL).parent(canvasParentRef)

        // Creates particle vectors
        for (let i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
            particles.push(p5.createVector(p5.random(w), p5.random(h)))
        }
    }

    const draw = (p5) => {
        // Styling
        p5.background(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--main-bg-color'));
        p5.stroke(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--main-text-color'));
        p5.translate(-w / 2, -h / 2)
        p5.strokeWeight(3)


        // Brains of the flow feild, takes the positions and modifies the particles positions given by noise.
        for (let i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
            let p = particles[i]
            p5.point(p.x, p.y)
            let n = p5.noise(p.x * scl, p.y * scl, zOff * 3);
            let angle = p5.TWO_PI * n
            p.x += Math.cos(angle) * speed
            p.y += Math.sin(angle) * speed
            if (!onScreen(p)) {
                p.x = p5.random(w)
                p.y = p5.random(h)
            }
        }

        zOff += 0.002
    }

    const onScreen = (v) => {
        return v.x >= 0 && v.x <= w && v.y >= 0 && v.y < h
    }

    const windowResized = (p5) => {
        w = p5.windowWidth;
        h = p5.windowHeight;
        nums = Math.ceil((w + h) / 1.5)
        p5.resizeCanvas(w, h);
        // Creates particle vectors
        for (let i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
            particles.push(p5.createVector(p5.random(w), p5.random(h)))
        }
    };

    return (
        <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} windowResized={windowResized} />
    )
}

export default Flow
```

I start with an initial size for my browser window, say 1000 x 1000. Whenever I increase the size of the window (by either dragging or fullscreening), the sketch crashes. Why is that? If I shrink the window, then everything continues to work (fullscreen or drag to bigger window). In essence, given an original sized window, I cannot drag the window to be larger

Comment: Try debouncing the resize.

Comment: What do you mean, debouncing

Comment: Did you try searching the term? Perhaps start with [What is the "debounce" function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/what-is-the-debounce-function-in-javascript).

Comment: Yes, to throttle how often the function fires when the window is resized. Sorry, i meant, is there debouncing built into p5, or is it some react function?

Comment: It's not built into either, as far as I know, so you'll need a separate package or roll it yourself (it's a small/simple function). Your code isn't runnable so I'm just guessing that the crash is because it's doing too much work. Even if there's some other factor, it's still good to debounce because you only want to run the redraw after the user has stopped resizing for 100ms (or whatever), rather than redrawing and destroying hundreds of times as they drag along. You may also want to clear the `particles` array--not sure what the intent is there, but I'm guessing that's adding more work too.