# How to stop the execution of a listener when a new event occurs?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a small web app and I dont want to use a js framework. That's why I am encouring some issues now.

The following snippet is responsible for the navigation. When a popstate event occurs, it show the spinner, initiates the page and shows it.

```js
import spinner from "./pages/spinner/spinner.js";
import dashboard from "./pages/dashboard/dashboard.js";
import grid from "./pages/grid/grid.js";

const pages = {
    dashboard,
    grid,
};

window.addEventListener("popstate", async () => {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    body.replaceChild(await createMain(spinner), document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0]);

    const route = window.location.hash.replace(/#/g, "");
    const page = pages[route];

    const initiatedPage = await page.init(await createMain(page));
    body.replaceChild(initiatedPage, document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0]);
});

history.pushState(null, null, "#dashboard");
window.dispatchEvent(new PopStateEvent("popstate", null));

async function createMain(page) {
    const template = await fetch(page.templateUrl);

    const main = document.createElement("main");
    main.classList.add(...page.classes);
    main.innerHTML = await template.text();

    return main;
}
```

Problem:

- If a user now clicks a link twice the code inside the listener runs in parallel and have some side effect.

I need to find a solution where the second clicks stops the execution of the first one.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think you may want to look into using a [debounce function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/what-is-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you want to second click just stop executing first one, or it should trigger the same function, just after stopping previous one?

Comment: Trigger the same function but stopping the previous execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We introduce 3 globals: `busy`, `cancel`, and a `pending` function

Whenever we trigger our `process` function, we check if we're already `busy`. If this is the case we raise the `cancel` flag, schedule ourself to run later as a `pending` function, and quit.

On the other hand, if we are not too `busy` we start `process` right away, not forgetting to raise the `busy` flag so we won't be interrupted.

In any event of a `cancel` flag, we quit. If anything is `pending`, now it's the time to re-call it.

Considering the events-loop and the single threaded javascript runtime, next solution would work without dead locks or race conditions. Hopefully.

```js
let busy = false
let cancel = false
let foo_pending = null

// this function is generic! use it.
async function triggerProcess(process, elem) {
  if (busy) {
    cancel = true
    foo_pending = function() {
      triggerProcess(process, elem)
    }
    return
  }

  busy = true
  cancel = false
  foo_pending = null

  try {
    await process(elem)
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex)
  } finally {
    busy = false
  }

  if (foo_pending) {
    foo_pending()
  }
}


// this is your long process function
// add strategic points to cancel
async function process(elem) {

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    await delay(500)
    
    // a chance to cancel after "await"
    if (cancel) {
    
      // console.log(elem.innerText + " canceled!")
      return
    }
  }

  output.innerText = elem.innerText
}


async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

```html
<p>Click for a 1 second process:
</p>
<button onclick="triggerProcess(process, this)">A</button>
<button onclick="triggerProcess(process, this)">B</button>
<button onclick="triggerProcess(process, this)">C</button>
<button onclick="triggerProcess(process, this)">D</button>
<div id="output" style="font-size: 48px">?</div>
```