How can I refactor the existing useEffect to useMemo hook for filtering the colors array?
I have use two state variables to the filter colors search, resultantColors.
The existing useEffect watches the search from the input and then sets the filtered array. But these effects runs on every input changes, how can i possibly refactor the useEffect to useMemo so that i can able to reduce the re-renders ?
Also, Does useMemo support all the lifecycle methods for componentDidMount(empty array dependency), componentWillUnmount as we wanted to refactor the existing useEffect (component DidUpdate Lifecycle) ? - Can give yes or no for this one.
Live demo
I have tried to reduce the re-renders, but for this example the useEffect runs on every change, it get triggers every time. Also if does useMemo handles all equivalent lifecycle of useEffect ?
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const mockColors = ['white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [resultantColors, setResultantColors] = useState(mockColors);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (search == '') {
      setResultantColors(mockColors);
    } else {
      const resultColors = resultantColors.filter((color) =>
        color.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
      setResultantColors(resultColors);
    }
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <div style={{ border: '1px solid blue', padding: 20, margin: 20 }}>
      Filter Example with UseEffect <br />
      <label htmlFor="colors">Filter Color:</label>
      <input
        type="search"
        name="search"
        value={search}
        id="colors"
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleInputChange(e);
        }}
        placeholder="filter colors"
      />
      {resultantColors.length > 0 ? (
        resultantColors.map((value, index) => (
          <>
            <li key={`${value} + ${index}`}>{value}</li>
          </>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>No items - search existing value </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;




Are you purposely re-filtering resultantColors again in your useEffect? This will make it so that if you search ee (giving green), and the replace your search with n you'll only get green back, not green and orange

Remove the resultantColors state, and calculate it whenever search changes:


const { useMemo, useState } = React;

const mockColors = ['white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];

function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };
  
  const resultantColors = useMemo(() => 
    search == ''
    ? mockColors
    : mockColors.filter(color =>
      color.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    )
  , [search]);

  return (
    <div style={{ border: '1px solid blue', padding: 20, margin: 20 }}>
      Filter Example with UseEffect <br />
      <label htmlFor="colors">Filter Color:</label>
      <input
        type="search"
        name="search"
        value={search}
        id="colors"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        placeholder="filter colors"
      />
      {resultantColors.length > 0 ? (
        resultantColors.map((value, index) => (
          <>
            <li key={`${value} + ${index}`}>{value}</li>
          </>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>No items - search existing value </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



Does useMemo support all the lifecycle methods for componentDidMount(empty array dependency), componentWillUnmount as we wanted to refactor the existing useEffect (component DidUpdate Lifecycle) ?
useMemo returns the cached value if the dependencies parameters are identical, or recomputes the value if the dependencies change. On mount it computes the value and caches it for the 1st time, and on unmount it doesn't do anything. If you want to do something on unmount, or handle any side effect, you'll still have to use useEffect. You can use a combination of useMemo and useEffect blocks (you can use multiple) to handle different cases.

I might be missing something, but doesn't this do what you need ?


import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const mockColors = ['white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];

function App() {
  
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
};
  
const resultantColors = useMemo(() => {
    if (search == '') {
        return mockColors;
    } else {
        return mockColors.filter((color) =>
            color.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        );
    }
 }, [search]);

return (
    <div style={{ border: '1px solid blue', padding: 20, margin: 20 }}>
      Filter Example with UseEffect <br />
      <label htmlFor="colors">Filter Color:</label>
      <input
          type="search"
          name="search"
          value={search}
          id="colors"
          onChange={(e) => {
              handleInputChange(e);
          }}
          placeholder="filter colors"
      />
      {resultantColors.length > 0 ? (
           resultantColors.map((value, index) => (
              <>
                  <li key={`${value} + ${index}`}>{value}</li>
              </>
           ))
       ) : (
            <p>No items - search existing value </p>
       )}
</div>
  );
}

export default App;



I moved the constants for mockColors outside of the App declaration. You should also look at debouncing the change of the search value so that it doesn't cause the memoized collars to change as frequently. There are lots of examples on SO, for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24004942/23356563

To answer your second question first: No, useMemo does not support all the lifecycle methods in the same way as useEffect. useMemo is primarily for memoizing computed values, while useEffect is for side effects. useMemo doesn't have direct equivalents to componentDidMount or componentWillUnmount.


import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function App() {
  const mockColors = ['white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [resultantColors, setResultantColors] = useState(mockColors);

  const filterColors = useCallback(() => {
    if (search === '') {
      setResultantColors(mockColors);
    } else {
      const filtered = mockColors.filter((color) =>
        color.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
      setResultantColors(filtered);
    }
  }, [search]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    filterColors();
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ border: '1px solid blue', padding: 20, margin: 20 }}>
      Filter Example with useCallback <br />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="colors">Filter Color:</label>
        <input
          type="search"
          name="search"
          value={search}
          id="colors"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          placeholder="filter colors"
        />
        <button type="submit">Filter</button>
      </form>
      {resultantColors.length > 0 ? (
        resultantColors.map((value, index) => (
          <li key={`${value}-${index}`}>{value}</li>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>No items - search existing value </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;



